# Use two routers without daisy chaining (use like WLAN card)

Tags: router, wireless-router, ethernet, bridge-router

My WLAN card recently started losing quality but I just got a new router (and kept the old one). The problem is that the router is down one floor and we don’t have Ethernet going through the house.  So I was wondering if I could link the old router to the new one and put the old one upstairs and use the Ethernet connections instead of WLAN cards.

I know this is possible if you chain the two together with an Ethernet cable, but obviously that is unavailable. Anyway I can do this wirelessly? I’ve heard about bridging them, but I’m not entirely sure if that is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would need to know the model/revision of your routers you have currently.

If your routers support DD-WRT, you could do a "repeater bridge" setup with your second router to allow devices that are in range of the 2nd router to connect to the main router.  They'd still be "daisy-chained" in a sense, but the 2nd router will use the wireless signal for traffic and there will be no need for an ethernet cable between the two.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge

Since you mentioned using the downstairs computers/devices on Ethernet cables, you could do a client bridge instead of the repeater bridge.  In a "client bridge" setup, you would be only allowed to use wired connections on the second router.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged

If you do decide to go down the DD-WRT route, please read all the information regarding how to change over to DD-WRT.

Comment: Cool thanks! I've got an Archer c9 (base station) and a wndr3700

Comment: You would only need to DD-WRT the 2nd router, the first one can stay setup as it is currently.  Both routers come up in their supported router list. [DDWRT List](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#TP-Link) but be sure and check the revisions.  I've seen a router (was a netgear I think) that was supported on DD-WRT, but the newest revision wasn't.